# LWR and Privileged Script Tag

Tags: lwr, gtm

I need to configure Google Tag Manager for the LWR community.
But I'm stuck while sending GTM event.

GTM is configured this way and works

```
<x-oasis-script hidden="true">
    // gtag basic snippet code do not change
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    
    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    
    gtag('js', new Date());
    
    // the gtag config function to configure the measurement/property ID on the gtag tracker with other avilable settings i.e cookieDomain auto that sets the _ga cookie on the Top Level Domain of the page.
    // the configuration function sends a default pageview hit to Google Analytics Meaurement/Property ID i.e UA-XXXXXXXXX-X.
    
    gtag('config', 'GTM-PM123456', {
        'cookie_domain': 'auto',
    });
</x-oasis-script>
```

Inside the LWC component, I prepare a custom event to update the GTM data layer.

```
document.dispatchEvent(
    new CustomEvent(
        'dataLayerPushEvent',
        {
            'detail' : {
                'event': 'test_event'
            }
        }
    )
);
```

but x-oasis-script in head markup doesn't work

```
<x-oasis-script hidden="true">
    document.addEventListener('dataLayerPushEvent', function(e) {
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push(e.detail);
    }, false);
</x-oasis-script>
```

same code using a regular script tag works fine

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('dataLayerPushEvent', function(e) {
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push(e.detail);
    }, false);
</script>
```

What could be a cause?
What are the considerations for using a regular script instead of an x-oasis-script, other than not having access to the shadow DOM?